# 'value drop is not a member of String' although it should be (using IDEA12)

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have a problem with using methods on variables. Often the Scala compiler complains that no such method is available, even though my IDE (IDEA12) autocompletes the available method, and it is defined in the Scala Docs.

For example.

```
val x:String = "abc"
var y:String = null

y =  x.drop(1)
```

results in:

```
error: value drop is not a member of String
y =  x.drop(1)
```

Interesting the same occurred with:

```
var x = List.fromArray(y)      //why does this work and not below?
var x = y.toList
```

The first deprecated (and advise to use .toList) function works fine, the second method throws up the same "is not a member of" compile time error.

I am using Scala 2.10

Many thanks for any advice.

Edited to say this only occurs with strings, all other types are unaffected.
I seem to have the import "import scala.Predef.String" and removing this clears the errors however the compilation fails later on at the Proguard stage.

Comment: Are you _sure_ you are using Scala 2.10 to compile the code? How are you compiling it?

Comment: Hi there, this is IDEA 12 with the Android SDK, and yes the compiler is Scala 2.10.3.
C:\Users\ed>scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.3 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_0
9)

Comment: That's the REPL, not the Scala compiler. What are the precise steps that you are following to compile your Scala code?

Comment: I know this :) but this verifies the install was 2.10 as it is the only Scala on the platform and the REPL version shouldn't differ. I am using a standard IDEA12 environment with a Scala facet. All the libraries are within the path, indeed most stuff compiles OK and run on the Droid. However you make me suspect a library issue.

Comment: @nfcpro IDEA can freely adjust it settings and use different scalac so although you will see 2.10 in REPL, actual IDEA project can use whatever version of scala it might want. **This** is why Robin asks how exactly you do compilation.

Comment: I have only one scalac build on my system, 2.10, and it using this, whilst compiler options might allow deprecation this is not set by default.

Comment: C:\Users\ed>scala>scalac -version
Scala code runner version 2.10.3 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL

C:\Users\ed>

Comment: Double check that IDEA is using scala 2.10, as mentioned before, yes you may only have scala 2.10 installed on your machine but IDEA can use its own compiler internally. When do you see this error? In the REPL embedded in IDEA? When you compile/run from IDEA? Do you see the same if you compile with scalac or sbt?

Comment: Code works in REPL OK, IDEA is configured to use 2.10 everywhere (Language Level and Libraries) and the compile time error occurs whether working in standard or fsc mode during a standard IDEA compile (object code is generated and runs OK otherwise with the methods removed). The library paths are all OK are verified. Very annoying issue, many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is how you disable Predef autoimport. (There's also the option `-Yno-predef`.)

```
scala> :pa -raw
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

import Predef.String
object X { "abc".drop(1) }

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

<pastie>:2: error: value drop is not a member of String
object X { "abc".drop(1) }
                 ^
There were compilation errors!
```

If you need to selectively disable:

```
scala> :pa -raw
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

import Predef.{ assert => _, _}
object X { "abc".drop(1) }

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.
```